# If more than one integers have the same number of zeros in their binary representation, the program does not sort based on the given order

Tags: python-3.x

question:
The program must accept N integers as the input. The program must sort the integers in ascending order based on the number of zeros in their binary representation. Then the program must print the N sorted integers as the output. If more than one integers have the same number of zeros in their binary representation, the program must sort those integers in the given order

```
n=int(input())
l=list(map(int,input().split()))
bc=[]
for i in range(n):
  b=bin(l[i])[2:]
  c=b.count('0')
  bc.append(c)
z=zip(bc,l)
g=[x for y,x in sorted(z)]
print(*g)
```

Input:
5
4 3 8 7 1

Output:
3 7 1 4 8

I'm expecting output as 3 7 1 4 8 but output I get is 1 3 7 4 8
The problem is if more than one integers have the same number of zeros in their binary representation, the program does not sort based on the given order in the question

Comment: There also should be a `5` in both correct and incorrect output.

Answer (score 0):

Is there is no particular reason to keep an additional array of counts, a simple sort `key` function can be used:

```
n=int(input())
l=list(map(int,input().split()))
l.sort(key = lambda e: bin(e)[2:].count('0'))
print(*l)
```

Input:

```
6
5 4 3 8 7 1
```

Output:

```
3 7 1 5 4 8
```